# Change of Variables : how to find u(x,y) and v(x, y) from x(u,v) and y(u,v)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the set of equations:

$$x(u,v) = u\cos\theta + v\sin\theta$$
$$y(u,v) = -u\sin\theta + v\cos\theta$$

Where $\theta$ is a constant angle.

I wish to be able to find $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$

The jacobian $=1 \neq 0$ for all $u$ and $v$ which I believe means it is invertable and therefore $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ exists.

Could someone please help me find $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ ?

Comment: The jacobian being non-zero only means that the function is *locally* invertible, by the way. Being global as a whole follows from $(x,y) \mapsto (u,v)$ being a linear map.

Answer (score 0):

The pair $(x,y)$ is found applying a rotation of $\theta$ to the pair $(u,v)$. Nothing is more natural than concluding that $(u,v)$ is found from $(x,y)$ by rotating it by $-\theta$. That is: $$\begin{align} u(x,y) &= x \cos (-\theta)+y \sin (-\theta) \\ v(x,y) &= -x \sin(-\theta) + y \cos(-\theta)\end{align}$$You can use that $\cos(-\theta) = \cos \theta$ and $\sin(-\theta)  =-\sin \theta$ to simplify this as you please.